# How do I change the web inspector font for Safari 8?

Tags: css, macos, safari, web-inspector

How can I modify the css for on Safari 8.0.2's Web Inspector on Yosemite 10.10.1?

I know the old way for previous versions has been to edit `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebInspector.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/Main.css` but on Safari 8 on Yosemite, that file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

2020 update, been looking into this, and you'll need to disable SIP on macOs to get this to work on Catalina. (Which you should only do if you REALLY know what you're doing) See also: https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos.

The location of the CSS file you'll need to modify on Catalina is located in:
`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebInspectorUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Main.css`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the file you're looking for:

`/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebInspectorUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Main.css`

Comment: This only applied to previous versions of Safari. I'm not sure about Safari 9 though.